# Which NVIDIA graphic driver version to select in Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 15 L501X

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, dell

I am new to Ubuntu and have just installed 16.04 on my old XPS15. I tried to select the latest graphic driver for nvidia. Version 361.42 (proprietary, tested) and it wouldn't boot back into the GUI, so I drastically reinstalled ubuntu and now wanting to get it right a second time. I have looked at a large number of different posts on this forum with all kinds of work arounds but I am reluctant to try without making the situation worse. Could it be a matter of just chosing a more recent driver from NVIDIA site or could I select an older driver from the list to get it working? I have attached an image of the available drivers to choose from.[Additional drivers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDA1L.png)

Comment: According to Nvidia 361 should work (any ranging from 352 to 370 should support your card). I would fully update the system before trying 361 again.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: To fully update I did sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade. Is there anything else I need to do to upgrade before I switch the drivers to Nvidia 361.42?

Comment: Solved - Your suggestion Celtic Warrior did the trick. Just updated everything and it worked when I reinstalled following selecting 361.42.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty solid article on Ubuntu forums that seems to solve your issue here: [How to get Nvidia 420M working](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1579444)

Apologies for posting an answer that may not be fully correct. I would have posted a comment but my rep is not high enough yet.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this but as I have built in integrated intel graphics chip and the Nvidia one on the motherboard, seems like others with the same machine didn't manage to get it going with them workaround mentioned. Not sure whether to try this.

Comment: Couldn't hurt right?  I doubt you will damage anything by installing drivers or "make the situation worse" as you said.